# Import-cost discrepency in modularised npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm importing a part of the [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library in my project, but I basically only need to use the `eachlimit` function.

From previous experience with the library, I remember that there are (like Lodash) modularized packages like [async.eachlimit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async.eachlimit). however, they seem to be deprecated since the official package seems to support modular imports of the package:

[image: An instruction on the documentation of the async package, listing import instructions]

However, when actually using this import method, I see a huge difference in file size between the `async.eachlimit` and `async/eachlimit` import methods (provided by [`import-costs`](https://github.com/wix/import-cost))

```
import * as eachLimit from 'async.eachlimit'; // 2K (gzipped: 725)
import eachLimit from 'async/eachlimit';  // 10.7K (gzipped: 3.8K)
```

These are supposed to be the same library, albeit different versions, but this size difference seems immense for what should probably not be this big of a library.

So I'm not sure what's going wrong. Is this just `import-cost` being inaccurate, or could that specific package really have quintupled?

Comment: Side note: `import * as eachLimit from 'async.eachLimit'` imports the package's namespace object. I suspect you meant to import its default import: `import eachLimit from 'async.eachLimit';`.

Comment: I replaced the picture with code now. As for the side note: that's something that's on Typescript, they require that for some packages  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think you [might want to double-check that](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Again, it imports the namespace object, not the default import, creating the namespace object if it doesn't already exist. I don't buy that TypeScript requires that.